# How to get data flag from controller to jsp in Spring mvc, after executing all code from controller

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp

**This is my controller code.**

```
@RequestMapping(value={VspCommonConstants.INTERVIEW_PANEL_MANAGER_URL+"/submitAssessmentform"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitAssessmentform(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
boolean saveFlag=false;
        try {


         saveFlag = interviewQuestionResultService.saveInterviewQuestionRemark(actualData, list,new Long(Appid),new Long(uInfo.getId()),existFlag,
                VspCommonConstants.getIpFromRequest(request),new Long(uInfo.getId()));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            saveFlag=false;
        }
        model.addAttribute("saveFlag",saveFlag);
        return view;
    }
```

**At jsp i'm taking 'saveFlag' in document.ready function as follows**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var saveFlagValue = $("#saveFlag").val();   
                         alert("saveflag:"+saveFlagValue); 

                        if(saveFlagValue == "true"){
                             /* swal("Error","Data saved successfully .","error");  */
                             swal({
                                html : true,
                                title : '<i></i>',
                                text : '<b>Data saved successfully.</b>'
                            }); 
                        } 

                    });
```

**Now i wanted to have this saveFlag only after controller executes its all code. But unfortunitely im getting the data when my page get loaded. and i want this saveFlag when form is submitted and get response from controller, not at starting. Please help me solve the problem. Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

In the JSP, you should wrap your jQuery code into this tag :

```jsp
<c:if test="${not empty saveFlag}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {...}
    </script>
</c:if>
```

When the user first arrive on the page, the `saveFlag` is empty since the controller has not been called. In consequences, the jQuery code won't be executed. But when the form is submitted, the `saveFlag` is will be `true` or `false` and success / error message will be displayed.